asp.net vb vs2022 oAuth Timing out
I'm running the code below. It'll run for almost 2 minutes and then throw an error stating "The task was canceled".
I work solo and am hoping to get another set of eyes on this to find the problem.  If you need my secret I can pm  it to you.
Thanks
 Protected Async Sub BtnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGo.Click
 Dim Test As String = Await AsyncCall(Nothing)

End Sub
Protected Async Function AsyncCall(ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Task(Of String)
 Dim clientId As String = "4e502cbc-a55f-4341-a498-69cfbe19ee7b"
 Dim clientSecret As String = "my sercret goes here"

 Dim credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret)
 Dim headerValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials))

 Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
                                 {"client_id", clientId},
                                 {"client_secret", clientSecret},
                                 {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
                                 {"scope", "https://tffproduction.onmicrosoft.com/04cc9749-dbe5-4914-b262-d866b907756b/.default"}
                                 })

 Dim requestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ca4f5969-c10f-40d4-8127-e74b691f95de/oauth2/v2.0/token")
 requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerValue)
 requestMessage.Content = content

 Dim responsemessage As HttpResponseMessage

 Dim client As New HttpClient

 Try
     responsemessage = Await client.SendAsync(requestMessage)

     If responsemessage.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
         Dim responseContent As String = Await responsemessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

         Return responseContent
     Else

         Return "Error: " & responsemessage.StatusCode.ToString()
     End If
 Catch ex As Exception

     Return "Error: " & ex.Message
 End Try

End Function
